# run_when_backgrounded and invisible() state in BlackBerry 10

Tags: background-process, blackberry-10, invisible, blackberry-cascades, qtimer

I'm implementing a BlackBerry 10 Cascade application. It uses a QTimer class and has the following code.

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
```

This is working and calling to update() function according to the given time period. It works when the application in foreground (application takes the entire screen) and also  when the application is running as an active frame (application is in thumbnail state).

I have given following permission also in bar-descriptor.xml.

```
<permission>run_when_backgrounded</permission>
```

But when a user press the cross mark (☓) the whole process stop. According to the [BB10 Cascade Documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/fundamentals/)

> When an app has permission to run in the background, there is no
>   Stopped state

What I want to know,

1.) Is there a way that we can programmatically eliminate the cross mark (☓) when it is in active frame ?

If Not

2.) How can I run a QTimer even if the application is stopped? Simply How can I run a background process without a UI when my cascade app is stopped.

3.) Is it enough providing **run_when_backgrounded** permission in the *bar-descriptor.xml* to run an application in background?

In the same documentation page under ***Managing application states***, there is `invisible()` state. But the [example](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__application.html#function-invisible) given there cannot implement in a cascade application class which include following

```
#include <bb/cascades/Application>
```

Is that only for     `#include <bb/Application>` ?

Comment: Background (headless) apps will be supported with 10.2. At the moment you can't run your app without having at least active frame

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an headless app. You'll find anything you need [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/headless_apps.html). Basically, you have two modes: event-based (your app will be launched to react to an event like an incoming SMS), or always running. Always running apps will need BlackBerry approval.

Note that the headless apps are not yet supported. They are introduced in the 10.2 SDK, which has been released as gold yesterday. You'll need a 10.2 OS too (which has not been deployed yet, except [test, stripped down versions](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalpha/devalpha_update.html)) to use them.

The `invisible` state you're talking about concerns non-headless apps: an application is considered visible if it's on foreground, invisible if it's in active frame state, or if there's another app in front of it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try on this. I need always running feature. As you say, it needs BlackBerry approval. First I need to implement a test application. I'll try to get approval on this. Caz seems there are no any other option for me.